# inserting Å Ä Ö into mysql database table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

```
<?php
$insert =  "I want to store Å Ä Ö in my database";

mysql_query(" INSERT INTO test (text) VALUE ('$insert')") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Just by using this piece of code, the database stopped storing data as fast as a special symbol (Å Ä Ö) was encountered so in this case I would only find the string "I want to store " in my database table. However I tried to put:

```
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

before the INSERT script, it worked somewhat better but now the issue is that all the special symbols are replaced with question marks ( ? ) in the database tables. My table collation is utf8_swedish_ci. The meta, charset is UTF-8.

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of PHP.

Comment: [**See this article**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) on SO, it may help.

Comment: @EugenRieck your comments have meant that any useful comments like Fred's comment are now drowned in useless chatter between you and Jocelyn. Jocelyn - Eugen is right, and if you have to post the standard "deprecated blah blah" then at least put some proper references in so the OP can follow it up easily.

Comment: I feel it's prudent as software professionals to offer advice where we see a knowledge deficit. There's far too many bad examples of using the *mysql* extension, including StackOverflow questions. New developers continue to find this information therefore there's nothing wrong with providing a comment around deprecated libraries. That being said, I agree with @scrowler, references should be provided. I like to use [this question and subsequent answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) as my canonical source.